# Adobe Analytics- Email campaign tracking

Tags: adobe, analytics, adobe-analytics

My organization sends out various emails to users and we want to track **" How many users clicked on the links in that particular email sent out by our team?"**.
How do we track this in Adobe Analytics & Reporting?
Right now I am only able to see, how many people clicked on the links in  all the emails combined  but I am not able to differentiate among various emails sent by our team

-Arjun Patil

Comment: In most cases you need to tag links in your email with parameters. This will allow you to distinguish clicked links in analytics. Check your implementation and see what it the name of parameter, which you should add.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Append a query parameter to your Email landing page URL, which user will click on.
For example: [www.mysite.com/landingpage?cmp=my_email_campaign_name](http://www.mysite.com/landingpage?cmp=my_email_campaign_name)

Then set up Adobe Analytics tracking code to capture this code and pass it to s.campaign variable or any other eVar used for campaign tracking.

```
s.campaign=s.Util.getQueryParam("cmp")
```